# Making UICollectionView With Images From URLs More Efficient

Tags: performance, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollection View with cells that contain images from the web. I use the EGOImageView class to load the images in the background, however with really large images there is about a half a second freeze on the iPhone and on the iPad it is very noticeable. Is there anything I can do to make it more efficient? Is there a way to download a compressed version of large images?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a thumb version for every image.
Download will speed up a lot!

Comment: I know but these are images downloaded from Google Reader so I can't control the size.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial: http://brian-erickson.com/uiimage-thumbnails-in-objective-c-for-the-iph